# Using "apt-get -f install" In Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'd like to run the `apt-get --fix-broken install` command in Ansible. It doesn't work if I use `command: apt-get -f install`, and [the `apt` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html) doesn't appear to provide a parameter for specifying that option. How can I do it in Ansible?

Comment: What's the error message? Try adding `-y` to the command.

Comment: It works. Before adding `-y`, it seems the error happened because it didn't answer `Do you want to continue? [Y/n]` question

Answer (score 2):

Codifying my (apparently helpful) answer from the comments:

Try adding `-y` to the command.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to set the `state` to `fixed` via the [`apt` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html).  The `-f` parameter [is used to fix broken dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58378/what-exactly-does-sudo-apt-get-f-install-do).

The docs for Ansible list several different values for the `state` parameter:

- `absent` *ensure the package is not installed*
- `build-dep` *ensures the package build dependencies are installed.*
- `latest` *ensures that the latest version is installed*
- `present`(default) *ensures the package is installed at any version*
- `fixed` *attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.*

Something like:

```
- name: update package
  apt:
    name:  my_package
    state: fixed
```

Comment: The question does not specify a package name. So having "name:  my_package" is not correct